windows 11 widgets is not picking up my profile
Upgraded to windows 11 23H2 and since then my widgets does not have my profile button. So there is no news feeds just weather, games and shopping. When i go to settings i get "No feeds here to personalise" "Add feeds to personalise" then a blue spinning circle appears then that's it.
I have reinstalled windows web experience pack. anyone any ideas?

General computing questions, including Windows-specific questions, are off-topic here, as they are not related to programming. The correct site is [su] - just be sure to read the guidelines first.
